# How to achieve spacing in between specific subplots using plotly express dash- Python

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js

For my webapp, I have 6 plotly line subplots arranged in 6 rows and 1 column with shared x-axis. I am able to plot all the 6 subplots either without spaces between them or having same spacing between each. However, I want spacing only after 2nd and 4th subplots with shared x-axis. Vertical_spacing property is applying to all subplots for spacing. But my use case is to provide space only after specific subplots. Can anyone help me how to proceed for this?

I want spacing after specific subplots but not all using plotly dash (python)